# Unable to load data inside ngOnInit

Tags: angular

My goal is to load a dropdown when a component renders.
I have a service which hits a url and gets json data. Something like this

```
 @Injectable()
 export class StudentListService {

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

 studentListUrl: string ="http://www.somecollege.com/students";

 public getStudentList() {
    return this.http.get(this.studentListUrl);
}
```

I have a component (StudentListComponent) which would display student names that I get from the service, in a dropdown.

```
 export class StudentListComponent implements OnInit {
    items: any = [];

    constructor(private studentListService: StudentListService){}

    ngOnInit() {
       this.items = this.studentListService.getStudent().subscribe(
           data => {this.items = data},
           err => console.error(err),
           () => console.log('Done Loading Student Data'));

       //////////  Here this.items is undefined 

    }
```

However if I put a button on StudentListComponent html and use its click event to display this.items, I see the data

```
 buttonClicked() {
  console.log(this.items); /// see the students in console)
 }
```

Why is this.items undefined in ngOnInit() and how can I get the data to populate when the component renders?

Comment: You can only access it once the `http` (asynchronous) call is completed. And when it is completed, your dropdown should automatically load those items. If you try to print it oustide `subscribe` block, it gives you undefined.

Comment: So how to wait till the call is complete? Where should I put the code that populates the dropdown?

Comment: Once the asynchronous call is completed `this.items` will automatically bind to dropdowns.

Comment: I see that the method names used in the component and the service are different. I hope it is a typo.

Comment: @Amit where exactly should I put the code that binds the data to the dropdown?

Comment: @bluepiranha Can you please show how you are binding the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Amit mentioned, since this is an async call, your data won't be available untill the `subscribe` block runs. So you won't be having access to data outisde it

Read the comments in the below code to understand:

```
export class StudentListComponent implements OnInit {
  items: any = [];

  constructor(private studentListService: StudentListService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.studentListService.getStudent().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.items = data;
        //////////  Here this.items WILL BE DEFINED
      },
      err => console.error(err),
      () => console.log('Done Loading Student Data'));

    //////////  Here this.items WILL BE undefined as this will run synchronously i.e. it won't wait for this.studentListService.getStudent() to run.

  }

}
```

Comment: `this.items = this.studentListService.getStudent().subscribe()` is wrong, it is assigning `Subscription` to `this.items`

Comment: @HarunYılmaz, thanks a lot for pointing that out. Updated the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ngOnInit() {
       setTimeout(()=>
          {
            this.studentListService.getStudent().subscribe(response =>{
             this.items = response;
          },error=>{
           console.log(error);
         });
     },1000);
 }
```

Comment: It's always nice to put some explanation when you give an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `getStudentList` method of the service returns an `Observable` therefore it is an `async` function. So `data => {this.items = data}` line performs only after the subscription is completed. But `this.items` is not **undefined** since you assign it an empty array with `items: any = []`, it is only **empty**.

You can log the values with `buttonClicked` method because your http request has been completed.

I think you need to get more familiar with `Observable` from `RxJS`.

Here is the official docs of `HttpClient`: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: So where should I put the code which populates the dropdown?

Comment: the undefined is coming from the `this.items = this.studentListService.getStudent().subscribe(` part - the result of subscribe() is assigned to this.items for a very short period of time until it is overwritten by the success callback hander again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this assignment  `this.items = this.studentListService.getStudent()...`. You are trying to assign `Subscription` object to `this.items`.

```
ngOnInit() {
       this.studentListService.getStudent().subscribe(
           data => {this.items = data},
           err => console.error(err),
           () => console.log('Done Loading Student Data'));

}
```

**Note** : You can only access it once the `http` (asynchronous) call is completed. And when it is completed, your dropdown should automatically load those items. If you try to print it outside `subscribe` block, it gives you undefined.