# Data not being populated in ngOnInit in Angular

Tags: angular, ngoninit

I am calling a dummy web API to populate a variable of class to use it further but then I came across an odd scenario which is confusing me:

```
export class myClass implements OnInit{ 
    data : any;    
    constructor (private http:HttpClient){}
    ngOnInit(){  
        this.http.get("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/82342").subscribe(e=>this.data = e);
        alert("beforeConsole");        
        console.log(this.data);
        var size = Object.keys(this.data).length;
        alert(size); 
    }
}
```

Variable data is populating only when i am using `alert` ( Just for checking). IF I remove  `alert("beforeConsole");` then console gives me `undefined`.

I am not able to understand this. Please suggest what's actually going on.

Comment: When do get undefined. Also try to use `console.log` not `alert` to debug your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Comment: i tried console.log but its gives me as         console.log(this.data) gives me undefined if i do not use         alert("beforeConsole");

Comment: try this... `ngOnInit(){  
 this.http.get("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/82342").subscribe(
 e=> {this.data = e;         alert("beforeConsole");        
         console.log(this.data);
         var size = Object.keys(this.data).length;
          }
 () => {alert(size);}
 );
    }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to load data inside ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54519854/unable-to-load-data-inside-ngoninit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Http.get returns an Observable and is asynchronous.
Your console.log runs before the request has time to process.

Move your console.log inside your subscribe as this will run once the observable is emitted.

```
this.http.get("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/82342")
   .subscribe(e => { 
     this.data = e;
     console.log(this.data);
     var size = Object.keys(this.data).length;
   });
```

Comment: There are enough answers to such questions already in here. Instead of answering the question, please consider marking it as duplicate. This would help make StackOverflow less polluted. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest You to use async await.

```
ngOnInit(): void { this.initialize(); }

async initialize(): Promise<void> {
  try {
    this.data = await this.http.get("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/82342").toPromise();
    console.log(this.data);
  } catch (e) { console.error(e); }
}
```