# Angular 7+ error: 'the property is not available on type Object'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using a service to make a simple HTTP get request to an API and the request is successful. I get back an object with properties and their values and when I subscribe and log the response all seem to work fine. If I then try to access a property on the response eg(console.log(response.title), I get an error that the property is not available on the object. What's strange to me is that the properties are defined as part of the response object. If I ignore the error, the program compiles and serves on Localhost and the same property giving an error is logged to the console. I even used the same property to output text in the DOM and it is rendered yet still the error shows and it does this on all properties of the response object. Is this a bug or am I missing something? I don't want to change the response because it's already an object which is exactly what I want.

Comment: Can you add a stackblitz demo or code to understand better.

Comment: Provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You probably are trying to read the properties on the `response` outside the `subscribe` block. If that's actually the case, read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54519854/unable-to-load-data-inside-ngoninit) on this thread.

Comment: I am doing everythig in the subscribe block and the values actually get logged in the console

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ziheza?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest.service.t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's strange to me is that the properties are defined as part of the response object.

Doesn't matter. The error you're getting are TypeScript static errors. At the compile time, TypeScript has no idea of the shape of the response from API. You can tell it: where you have your `http.get(//...args)`, specify: `http.get</* type declaration here */>(//... args)`, even `http.get<any>//...` should solve the problem.

You can also do that during consumption: `console.log((response as any).title)`, for example.

Here's a fork of your stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ziheza?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest.service.ts